# Kubernetes 1.6 Auto Provisioning With NFS

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine

The newly stable [Auto-Provisioning features](http://blog.kubernetes.io/2016/10/dynamic-provisioning-and-storage-in-kubernetes.html) of Kubernetes seemingly eliminates the need to define `PersistentVolume`s and, based on its `StorageClass`, result in a `PersistentVolumeClaim` just having its needs met.

This all seems a bit simpler but I'm at a bit of a loss what to do when it comes to updating my manifests for the [canonical NFS example](http://blog.kubernetes.io/2016/10/dynamic-provisioning-and-storage-in-kubernetes.html)

Before 1.6, the following PVC and PV would be bound together and several other services could use the ReadWriteMany PVC `nfs-pvc` without problem

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nfs
  namespace: staging
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Mi
  accessModes: [ "ReadWriteMany" ]
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  nfs:
    # FIXME: use the right IP
    server: 10.7.252.23
    path: "/exports"
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nfs-pvc
  namespace: staging
spec:
  accessModes: [ "ReadWriteMany" ]
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Mi
```

(Please note i have only now added the `persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy` but does not affect things)

However, in 1.6, running this manifest results in an additional PV `pv/pvc-75f9e8d1-1f69-11e7-b065-42010a84002d`. Presumably this is due to the auto-provisioning. Unfortunately, this isn't NFS.

```
Matthews-iMac:gke matt$ k get pv,pvc
NAME                                          CAPACITY   ACCESSMODES   RECLAIMPOLICY   STATUS      CLAIM                            STORAGECLASS   REASON    AGE
pv/nfs                                        1Mi        RWX           Delete          Available                                                             18m
pv/postgres-volume                            100Gi      RWO           Retain          Bound       default/postgres-storage-claim   fast                     16h
pv/pvc-630748eb-1f69-11e7-b065-42010a84002d   100Gi      RWO           Delete          Bound       staging/nfs-server-pvc           standard                 18m
pv/pvc-75f9e8d1-1f69-11e7-b065-42010a84002d   1Gi        RWX           Delete          Bound       staging/nfs-pvc                  standard                 18m

NAME                 STATUS    VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESSMODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
pvc/nfs-pvc          Bound     pvc-75f9e8d1-1f69-11e7-b065-42010a84002d   1Gi        RWX           standard       18m
pvc/nfs-server-pvc   Bound     pvc-630748eb-1f69-11e7-b065-42010a84002d   100Gi      RWO           standard       18m
```

I think i may be missing something with regard to `selector` or something? I tried adding `selector -> matchLabel` but this isn't supported by the GCE provisioner apparently. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

So, I think i got to the bottom of this. The [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#reclaim-policy)

around "Class" mentions that when the "admission plugin" is enabled (as it is on GKE), it is necessary to specify within the PVC a `storageClass: ""`. This effectively means the PVC will only be considered for PVs that have no `storageClass`.

This is my updated manifest:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nfs
  namespace: staging
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Mi
  accessModes: [ "ReadWriteMany" ]
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  nfs:
    # FIXME: use the right IP
    server: 10.7.252.23
    path: "/exports"
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nfs-pvc
  namespace: staging
spec:
  accessModes: [ "ReadWriteMany" ]
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Mi
  storageClassName: "" # setting this to empty means this pvc can only be bound to pv with no class (i.e. not dynamically provisioned!)
```

And my bound instances:

```
Matthews-iMac:gke matt$ k get pv,pvc
NAME                                          CAPACITY   ACCESSMODES   RECLAIMPOLICY   STATUS     CLAIM                            STORAGECLASS   REASON    AGE
pv/nfs                                        1Mi        RWX           Delete          Bound      staging/nfs-pvc                                           5m
pv/postgres-volume                            100Gi      RWO           Retain          Bound      default/postgres-storage-claim   fast                     18h
pv/pvc-1d61980f-1f67-11e7-b065-42010a84002d   1Gi        RWX           Delete          Released   staging/nfs-pvc                  standard                 2h
pv/pvc-630748eb-1f69-11e7-b065-42010a84002d   100Gi      RWO           Delete          Bound      staging/nfs-server-pvc           standard                 1h

NAME                 STATUS    VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESSMODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
pvc/nfs-pvc          Bound     nfs                                        1Mi        RWX                          5m
pvc/nfs-server-pvc   Bound     pvc-630748eb-1f69-11e7-b065-42010a84002d   100Gi      RWO           standard       1h
Matthews-iMac:gke matt$
```

Comment: Yes, the PVC and PV joined as intended